# Target elements with multiple classes, within one rule

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

I have some HTML that would have elements with multiple classes, and I need to assign them within one rule, so that the same classes could be different within different containers. Say I have this in my CSS:

```
.border-blue {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.background {
    background: url(bg.gif);
}
```

Then I have this in my HTML:

```
<div class='border-blue background'>Lorum Crap No-one Cares About Ipsum</div>
```

Can I target these within a single rule? Like this, for example, which I know doesn't work:

```
.border-blue, .background {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: url(bg.gif);
}
```

Answer (score 257, accepted):

`.border-blue.background { ... }` is for when both classes are used together.

*Targets only the first*

```
<div class="border-blue background"></div>
<div class="border-blue"></div>
<div class="background"></div>
```

---

`.border-blue, .background { ... }` is for either class.

*Targets both*

```
<div class="border-blue"></div>
<div class="background"></div>
```

---

`.border-blue .background { ... }` is for where '.background' is the child of '.border-blue'.

*Targets only the second '.background' element*

```
<div class="border-red">
    <div class="background"></div>
</div>
<div class="border-blue">
    <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

See [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7270033/142410) for a more thorough explanation. Also see [W3 Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) on CSS Combinators

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know if this was possible, so I was asking here to find out.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me (or doesn't work anymore...).

Comment: you need to separate by commas the classes, as the Chris's answer tells

Comment: what do you mean in `.border-blue .background { ... }` is child? i tried this and this does not work

Answer (score 198):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this like I did and doesn't realise, the two variations above are for different use cases.

The following:

```
.blue-border, .background {
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    background: #fff;
}
```

is for when you want to add styles to elements that have either the blue-border or background class, for example:

```
<div class="blue-border">Hello</div>
<div class="background">World</div>
<div class="blue-border background">!</div>
```

would all get a blue border and white background applied to them.

However, the accepted answer is different.

```
.blue-border.background {
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    background: #fff;
}
```

This applies the styles to elements that have both classes so in this example only the `<div>` with both classes should get the styles applied (in browsers that interpret the CSS properly):

```
<div class="blue-border">Hello</div>
<div class="background">World</div>
<div class="blue-border background">!</div>
```

So basically think of it like this, comma separating applies to elements with *one class OR another class* and dot separating applies to elements with *one class AND another class*.

Comment: Just be careful. There are no spaces in `.blue-border.background`

Comment: `think of it as AND and OR` : Great advice. I might add that `.x .y` can be thought of as `y && ancestors.has(x)`