# Class name with space in it - Editing CSS in Shopify

Tags: class, shopify, classname

I'm trying to add a shadow to my product boxes in Shopify, but the class name has a space in it. It looks like this:

```
article class="item collection-product"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Shopify but to me, it looks like there are two classes. You would target them like this:

```
.item.collection-product {
    // CSS here
}
```

For classes you can use `.`, for IDs `#`.

You can apply multiple classes to anything, and all the CSS will apply in ascending order. So say class 1 has color blue, and class 2 comes after this in your CSS and has color green, color green would overwrite color blue unless you do something like `!important` for example:

```
.1class2{
    color: blue !important;
}

.class2{
    color: green;
}
```

Check this out for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7270033/142410