# What CSS selector to use for multiple classes targeting one HTML element?

Tags: css

This is what I have:

```
nav .class1, nav .class2, nav .class3 {property: value;}
```

This is what I want (or something similar):

```
nav (something) .class1, .class2, .class3 {property: value;}
```

Comment: Use a preprocessor.

Comment: Are those classes direct clhildren of nav? Are they the same tag?

Comment: CSS Selector rules separated by commas are entirely independent. You would have to use a preprocessor like SASS or LESS, but is there any way you can simplify your markup too?

Comment: This is just a quick example, the code is much more complex than this and the classes are not necessary direct children of the element nav. Each class has its properties and values but there are some other properties and values that those classes have in common thus why I was using the comma syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196583/target-elements-with-multiple-classes-within-one-rule Does this help?

Comment: Well, if you want a proper answer, you need to provide a proper pseudo code. Still, you won't be able to _minify_ CSS like that, but with e.g. SCSS your code could be simplified, though the compiled version of the same, will end up similar to what you have already.

Comment: @LGSon I was looking for a CSS selector that would make the first syntax similar to the second which I guess is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you could change your html, you could add a class to the elements you want to match,  like this:

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div class="class1 to-match"></div>
    <div class="class2 to-match"></div>
    <div class="other"></div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav > .to-match {property: value;}
```

If you can't change the HTML the only way to do this is with a preprocessor.

Comment: Some of them are pseudo classes, I have thought of doing something similar but it is not possible. I guess I'll need a preprocessor then.